# How do I select IDs that has same values?

Tags: sql

I have a table that has `UserID` and their `Books`. It's like this:

```
|UserID|Books|
--------------
|   a  |  a  |
--------------
|   b  |  a  |
--------------
|   b  |  b  |
--------------       
|   c  |  a  |
--------------
|   c  |  b  |
--------------
|   c  |  c  |
--------------
```

I want to get `UserID` that has same books with others.

For this table, I want to get a. What is the SQL command for this?

Comment: It's really really simple. Read the articles on [mysqltutorial.org](mysqltutorial.org) and add the code you tried.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.

Answer (score 2):

You can check each row to see if there are any other rows with a different user but the same book:

```
select books, userid
from user_book as ub1
where 0 < (select count(*) 
           from user_book as ub2
           where ub2.userid <> ub1.userid
           and   ub2.books = ub1.books )
```

example code: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/51bf2/1

However, I have the feeling that your question is vague and this maybe isn't what you really want, so clarify if necessary.

**---EDIT---**

To better meet to altered requirements:

```
select distinct userid
from user_book as ub1
where userid <> 'a'
and books in (
           select books 
           from user_book as ub2
           where ub2.userid = 'a' )
```

Working example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/51bf2/24

Comment: Too complex for nothing.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. You are right. The actual question is "List UserIDs that has the books that User1 has." User1 is coming from decision. So User1's books may be changeable. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

How about the below? It relies on using `&&` for array intersection, I hope it works for you.

```
with data_table as (
select user_id, array_agg(books) book_group -- this groups books for every user
from
(select -- this recreates your data
   unnest(array['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']) user_id,
   unnest(array['a', 'a', 'b', 'a' ,'b', 'c']) books) a
group by 1)

select data_table.user_id, data_table.book_group,
  data_table_other.user_id user_id_other,
  data_table.book_group && data_table_other.book_group and -- this checks intersection between book groups
  data_table.user_id != data_table_other.user_id is_book_shared
from data_table
left join data_table data_table_other
on True
order by 1, 3
```

Output:

```
    user_id book_group      user_id_other   is_book_shared
0   a       ['a']           a               False
1   a       ['a']           b               True
2   a       ['a']           c               True
3   b       ['a', 'b']      a               True
4   b       ['a', 'b']      b               False
5   b       ['a', 'b']      c               True
6   c       ['a', 'b', 'c'] a               True
7   c       ['a', 'b', 'c'] b               True
8   c       ['a', 'b', 'c'] c               False
```

Comment: Too complex for nothing.

Comment: very constructive, lets see your solution

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct UserID from table where Books = `a`
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The real question is "List UserIDs that has the books that User1 has." User1 is coming from decision. So User1's books may be changeable. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Like could be used if all nearly matching records are required.

```
select distinct UserID from table where Books like 'a%'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The real question is "List UserIDs that has the books that User1 has." User1 is coming from decision. So User1's books may be changeable. How can I do this?